# Chord Progression Questions

Tags: discussion, scope, subjective, questions

I would like to ask questions about when to use certain Chord progressions in music, but I feel that it might be too subjective. It really can't give a definitive answer.

I feel though that it leaves a lot of ground untouched. I'm sure there are a lot of opinions and knowledge on the subject that could help a composer like myself write music. Shouldn't we allow questions like these to be asked on the site? They may be subjective, but music is a subjective topic. (minus the theory) It just feels as though a lot of knowledge is passing us by. I'm sure it would attract more people to the site as well.

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of question you're asking about? There aren't really any right or wrong ways to use a certain chord progression—what matters is what kind of music you're trying to emulate. It is possible to ask questions about chord progressions that have objective answers, but "Do you like this?" and "What should I write next?" aren't really appropriate. See also http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/221/review-comment-on-this-piece-i-wrote

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can see good questions on topics such as chord progressions - when's / whys / hows - is exactly what this website is for.

I agree with @NReilingh, this isn't the place to ask for music reviews or directional advice, I don't however see a problem with say: **"This is a chord progression, these are my reasons for it, (is there a substitute?|why does it work over?|would you do it differently?|how do i modulate to..?|etcetera)"**

This website is not for people who 'know theory', its for every practising player/music enthusiast.